# Oracle View Data Transformation

Tags: sql, oracle, view

This is pertaining to Oracle 11g development. Can a column from its view definition be defined to transform its data?

For example,

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS SELECT Col1, Col2, TestColumn FROM TestTable;
```

For TestColumn, originating Table holds values= (True or False). But should be displayed as (Y,N) . How could I make this transformation happen on view?

1. Could User Defined Function be of any help that can be included in View definition?
2. using virtual transformation using $dpconf. ([Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E20295_01/html/821-1220/virtual-trans-examples.html))

Would approach would you recommend or is there a better solution? Appreciate your helpful inputs in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       DECODE( TestColumn, 0, 'N', 1, 'Y', null ) AS TestColumn
FROM   TestTable;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32564/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in query itself

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL='TRUE' THEN 'Y' WHEN COL='FALSE' THEN 'NO' END AS NEW_COL_NAME ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS SELECT Col1, Col2, 
CASE WHEN TestColumn = 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TestColumn FROM TestTable;
```